# Vinyl siding on concrete walls

Tags: insulation, siding, concrete-block, vinyl-siding

I have to install vinyl siding on an exterior wall built from concrete blocks.

Anyone have any tips on correctly weatherproofing and insulating? I was thinking to lay 3/4 EPS rigid insulation then 1/4 wood every foot and then tyvek wrap. After that I would install the siding.
Also, any tips for correctly insulating the bottom part of the building. It isnt level, so my vinyl would touch the floor at the front of the building but be almost a foot off the floor at the back. For reference (for insulation) I live in northeastern canada.
Thanks for any tips

Comment: Are you planning to tape the seams on the rigid insulation?  Also, you generally don't put housewrap over battens, just saying...

Comment: Yea i did some research and ended up getting the rigid board on the concrete and taped seams. Then the tyvek overtop then finally the battens